# Prevent Html Encode on String

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I prevent an a string variable which contains a few xml tags not to be html encoded in vb.

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`.

That should annul all HTML and keep anything entered as text.